# Relation aggregate function error in QGIS using Geometry by expression

Tags: qgis, error, expression, aggregation, geometry-generator

I have a point layer, consisting of 12 points with `fid` 1 to 12. I want to render points with fid > median (fid) - thus in this case, point 7 to 12.
That works perfectly if using geometry generator with this expression - see screenshot, where only 7 to 12 are rendered, whereas 1 to 6 only have labels/callouts:

```
if ( 
    "point_id" > median (
        "point_id"
    ), 
    $geometry , 
    ''
)
```

[image]

However, when I use the same expression with Menu Processing / Toolbox /Geometry by expression on the same point layer, I get an error: `Cannot use relation aggregate function in this context`. Why is that  - or asked the other way round: how to correct the expression? It's the same expression as in geometry generator in rather the same context.

I am asking specifically about this `relation aggregate function` error, as I already encountered it several times in more complex cases. In this simple case, of course there would be easier ways to achieve the goal. However, I wanted to present a simple case to make the error easier to reproduce.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using aggregate functions with processing it seems there is a scope problem.

For your problem, you should use the `aggregate` function and refer to the `layername` of your source point layer.

Something like that :

```
if (

    "point_id" > aggregate('<layername>','median', "point_id"), 
    $geometry , 
    geom_from_wkt('POINT EMPTY')
)
```

You need also to create a valid geometry point with `geom_from_wkt('POINT EMPTY')`

Comment: OK, works perfectly! It really seems that not only aggregate functions behave different in geometry generator and `Geometry by expression` tool, but empty outputs as well: in `Geometry by expression`, indeed only `geom_from_wkt('POINT EMPTY')` works, whereas in geometry generator, an empty output `''` works well.